# DacFX\SDDT - Disable Trigger operation inverted

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, sql-server-data-tools, dac

I have a table with an update trigger in it that must be updated.  The text of the update needs changed and the trigger must be left disabled.

For some reason when I run a Dac Deploy operation the software OMITS the disabling of the trigger in the analysis and the deploy.  He does update the text, but he enables the trigger!

The trigger is already disabled, but he enables it!  What the heck?

Is this a known issue or something?

I am just using a straightforward operation that works on almost every other case

```
[PublishResult] $PublishResult = $DacServices.Publish( $DacPackage, $TargetDatabaseName, $PublishOptions )
```

I have a restore and execute operation test case setup.  This happens every time I run it.

Restore DB: Trigger is disabled after restore
Execute: 5 Operations complete without errors
Test: Trigger text is updated as expected, but trigger is enabled

Happens every time I run this test.  I am thinking it's a bug

Comment: I just did some investigation and it appears this is not a bug, but expected behavior of sql server. Any alterations of disabled triggers will set the trigger to enabled when you are done. I guess Microsoft thinks if you change the content of a trigger that they're helping you out by enabling it without any notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior of MS Sql Server.  Performing ALTER statements on disabled triggers will implicitly enable the trigger.